# Function to gather user input on basic coin flip guessing program not behaving as expected

Tags: python, function

Total newbie here with only a few weeks of experience. I'm trying to code a simple coin flip guessing game. I've done it before solely using if statements and while loops, but I really want to try and do it using functions to push my understanding of python.

Below is the first function I wrote, which is meant to collect the user's guess. I put the print() statement in to confirm it's working properly.

My problem is that when I execute this code and enter "h", "t", or "q" as input, the function will loop once, only print out the result on the second loop, and then it will exit. The "else" statement seems to work fine.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why it is looping at all, and why it is only printing the result on the second loop. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
import random
print("Welcome to the coin flipper!")
def guess_gathering():
  user_guess = input("Pick [h]eads, [t]ails, or [q]uit:")
  if user_guess == "h":
    return 1
  elif user_guess == "t":
    return 2
  elif user_guess == "q":
    return "q"
  else:
    print("Invalid selection!")
    guess_gathering()
guess_gathering()
print(guess_gathering())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this bit right here:

```py
guess_gathering()
print(guess_gathering())
```

This runs the function twice.

If you want to only run it once, set the result to a variable:

```py
guess = guess_gathering()
print(guess)
```

Also, you must edit this bit of code:

```py
else:
    print("Invalid selection!")
    guess_gathering()
```

To this:

```py
else:
    print("Invalid selection!")
    return guess_gathering()
```

This change will make your program correctly return the value after it self-iterates.

Comment: Thank you. Still getting the hang of returns. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you call `guess_gathering` twice in the program. The following changes should work. Also, you might want to store the output of the variable in a function.

```py
import random

print("Welcome to the coin flipper!")
def guess_gathering():
  user_guess = input("Pick [h]eads, [t]ails, or [q]uit:")
  if user_guess == "h":
    return 1
  elif user_guess == "t":
    return 2
  elif user_guess == "q":
    return "q"
  else:
    print("Invalid selection!")
    guess_gathering()

output = guess_gathering()
print(output)
```

Comment: Consider if you accidentally entered an invalid selection, then did enter a valid selection, would your code output the "correct" value?

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Because of the missing return?

Comment: Yes, because of the missing return.